# Solve a polynomial equation of degree 4

Tags: matlab, polynomial-math, polynomials

I got this equation after I solved that problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124801/crossed-ladders-problem)

[image]

I would like to solve it using Matlab.

Comment: Probably because your question was trivial to solve.  A simple Google search could have given you the answer.  FWIW, I didn't downvote, as I obviously gave an answer :)

Comment: so what can i do to aviod this downvote could you edit to solve that problem please

Comment: @Educ: Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice - important here is that you do not show what you have tried, or explain what is preventing you from doing the work yourself. So someone has to guess what is wrong. In this case it is relatively easy to just give you a working piece of code, so you got your answer, but usually this type of question, where you just put a problem (that looks like a homework problem), then it is not so easy to help you - and perhaps the best help you could get is advice to do your studies, because you learn much less by going straight to the answer.

Comment: @Educ - It has nothing to do with you at all.  Downvotes are for those questions that "don't show any research effort", and this question (unfortunately) falls into that category.  As I said before, if you did a simple search, you would have found your answer immediately.  When I went to Google, I typed in `solve polynomial equations matlab` and the first link gave me the answer of what you were looking for.  In general, questions that can be solved by a simple search engine query ultimately get downvoted and closed as they're not useful.  However, please accept one of our answers when ready!

Comment: @Daniel it's been year that I asked that question I wish to delete it I got downvote so no need to accepting those answers

Answer (score 7):

The function `roots` returns polynomial roots. Simply pass the coefficients:

```
roots([1,-6,-36,216,-324])
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`solve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) from MATLAB's symbolic mathematics toolbox:

```
>> syms x;
>> y = solve('x^4-6*x^3-36*x^2+216*x-324==0')

y =

                                       7.7446378738164683022795580182987
                                      -6.3360292312480789716536487435108
 2.2956956787158053346870453626061 - 1.1543655214730370697054534567177*i
 2.2956956787158053346870453626061 + 1.1543655214730370697054534567177*i
```

The first line of code declares that `x` is a symbolic mathematics variable that we can use with the toolbox.  Next, we use `solve` and we put in a string that describes the equation that is seen in your post.  Bear in mind that when we multiply coefficients, you need to use the `*` operator, and for equality, we need to use double equals, or `==`.  The output should give you four roots, as dictated by the fundamental theorem of algebra.  You'll see that you have two real roots, as well as two imaginary roots.

Alternatively, you can use [`roots`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/roots.html) in MATLAB by specifying a vector of coefficients starting from the highest order down to the lowest [as per Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28265981/3250829).